# WSO2 API Manager with EnterpriseDb 9.5 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException: tuples must be non-null

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 with [Enterprise-db](https://www.enterprisedb.com/advanced-downloads) Advance Server (postgres) 9.5.
I have configured Postgres JDBC Driver ([postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar)) with it and configured all required data-sources required for WSO2-AM.
I am getting following error when start wso2-am server, please advise what is wrong here.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Uncaught underlying exception.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: tuples must be non-null
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.<init>(PgResultSet.java:147)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.createResultSet(PgStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(PgStatement.java:213)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2037)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:432)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:358)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:305)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.execSQLUpdate(PgConnection.java:480)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getTransactionIsolation(PgConnection.java:850)
```

Please Note: When i try to configure EDB-JDBC driver (edb-jdbc17.jar) with it gives different error. *Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unsupported database: EnterpriseDB. Database will not be created automatically by the WSO2 Registry. Please create the database using appropriate database scripts for the database.*
Creating db with scripts did not help.

Comment: I have bad feeling that the persistence layer doesn't recognize the EnterpriseDB as a Postgres Database. Maybe it could be worth the try - run the scripts (wso2am-2.0.0/dbscripts/postgresql.sql and wso2am-2.0.0/dbscripts/apimgt/postgresql.sql) before starting the WSO2AM (effective creating the schema).

Comment: I am getting this error now. any idea ? I executed both script.. (wso2am-2.0.0/dbscripts/postgresql.sql and wso2am-2.0.0/dbscripts/apimgt/postgresql.sql)   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin role has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin role in primary user store.

Comment: That's strange, postgresql is my favorite choice for WSO2 installations and it's working for versions from 9.2 to 9.6 (WSO2DAS needs 9.5+). The EnterpriseDB should be no different :/

Comment: Yes exactly, I am suprised too. With EnterpriseDb(9.5) what jdbc-driver i should use. I am little worried over choice if jdbc driver i should user... whethe ri should use postgres-jdbc-driver (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar) or i should use enterprisedb jdbc-driver as documented here https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.3/jdbc/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_JDBC_Connector_Guide-12.htm#TopOfPage